# Approach to upload multiple interconnected csv files to HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I am new to HBase and still not sure which component of Hadoop ecosystem I will use in my case and how to analyse my data later so just exploring options.

I have an Excel sheet with a summary about all the customers like this but with ≈ 400 columns:

```
CustomerID    Country    Age    E-mail
251648        Russia     27     boo@yahoo.com
487985        USA        30     foo@yahoo.com   
478945        England    15     lala@yahoo.com
789456        USA        25     nana@yahoo.com
```

Also, I have .xls files created separately for each customer with an information about him (one customer = one .xls file), the number of columns and names of columns are the same in each file. Each of these files are named with a CustomerID. A one looks like this:

```
'customerID_251648.xls':

feature1 feature2   feature3   feature4
0        33,878     yes        789,598
1        48,457     yes        879,594
1        78,495     yes        487,457
0        94,589     no         787,475
```

I have converted all these files into .csv format and now feeling stuck which component of Hadoop ecosystem should I use for storing and querying such a data.

My eventual goal is to query some customerID and to get all the information about a customer from all the files.

I think that HBase fits perfectly for that because I can create such a schema:

```
row key timestamp   Column Family 1                   Column Family 2           
251648             Country Age  E-Mail      Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature4
```

What is the best approach to upload and query such a data in HBase? Should I first combine an information about a customer from different sources and then upload it to HBase? Or I can keep different .csv files for each customer and when uploading to HBase choose somehow which .csv to use for forming column-families?

For querying data stored in HBase I am going to write MapReduce tasks via Python API.

Any help would be very approciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with schema design, also remember that hbase loads the whole column family during scans, so if you need all the data at one time maybe its better to place everything in one column family.

A simple way to load the data will be to scan first file with customers and fetch the data from the second file on fly. Bulk CSV load could be faster in execution time, but you'll spend more time writing code.

Maybe you also need to think about the row key because HBase stores data in alphabetical order. If you have a lot of data, you'd better create table with given split-keys rather than let HBase do the splits because it can end up with unbalanced regions.